# Gridview insert row

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, sql-server-2016

I am working on a website for an employer, currently using the NorthWInd database as an example. I am trying to add [this](https://www.codeproject.com/kb/webforms/completelistview.aspx) (The Insert part) to my website. Only problem being, the example shown there is for a list view, is it possible to do the same thing with a GridView?

Using C#, ASP.NET, HTML, Javascript, SQL

Whatever language is necessary.

**HTML**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Customer_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Customers | NorthWind Maintenance</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" BackColor="#B5C7DE" DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#284E98" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px">
            <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#284E98" ForeColor="White" />
            <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
            <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" />
            <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#507CD1" />
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Root" Value="Root">
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Customer/Default.aspx" Text="Customers" Value="Customers"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Products/Default.aspx" Text="Products" Value="Products"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Orders" Value="Orders"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Employees" Value="Employees"></asp:MenuItem>
                </asp:MenuItem>
            </Items>
            <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#284E98" ForeColor="White" />
            <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
            <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#507CD1" />
        </asp:Menu>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Customers"></asp:Label>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="1" DataKeyNames="CustomerID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GridLines="None" PageSize="25">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfProdID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("CustomerID")%>' />
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CustomerID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" SortExpression="CompanyName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="ContactName" SortExpression="ContactName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactTitle" HeaderText="ContactTitle" SortExpression="ContactTitle" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Region" HeaderText="Region" SortExpression="Region" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PostalCode" HeaderText="PostalCode" SortExpression="PostalCode" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" SortExpression="Country" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="Phone" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Fax" HeaderText="Fax" SortExpression="Fax" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Inactive" HeaderText="Inactive" SortExpression="Inactive" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#E7E7FF" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#DEDFDE" ForeColor="Black" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#9471DE" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#594B9C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#33276A" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthWindConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Customers]" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Customers] WHERE [CustomerID] = @CustomerID" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Customers] ([CustomerID], [CompanyName], [ContactName], [ContactTitle], [Address], [City], [Region], [PostalCode], [Country], [Phone], [Fax], [Inactive]) VALUES (@CustomerID, @CompanyName, @ContactName, @ContactTitle, @Address, @City, @Region, @PostalCode, @Country, @Phone, @Fax, @Inactive)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Customers] SET [CompanyName] = @CompanyName, [ContactName] = @ContactName, [ContactTitle] = @ContactTitle, [Address] = @Address, [City] = @City, [Region] = @Region, [PostalCode] = @PostalCode, [Country] = @Country, [Phone] = @Phone, [Fax] = @Fax, [Inactive] = @Inactive WHERE [CustomerID] = @CustomerID">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerID" Type="String" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerID" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CompanyName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ContactName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ContactTitle" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Region" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="PostalCode" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Country" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Phone" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Fax" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Inactive" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="CompanyName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ContactName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ContactTitle" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Region" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="PostalCode" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Country" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Phone" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Fax" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Inactive" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerID" Type="String" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:Button ID="Deactivate" runat="Server" Text="Deactivate Selected" OnClick="Deactivate_Click"/>
        <asp:Button ID="Activate" runat="server" Text="Activate Selected" Onlick="Activate_Click"/>
         <br />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so you need implementation thrrough gridview?

Comment: @Webruster Yeah, basically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample gridview markup

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="UserID"
            CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" ShowFooter="True">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UserID" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="UserID">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblUserID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UserName" SortExpression="UserName">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtfooterUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <%-- Here we Put the RequiredFieldValidator for textbox (txtfooterUserName) --%>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvUserName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtfooterUserName" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address1" SortExpression="Address1">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address1") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblAddress1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Address1") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtfooterAddress1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EmailAddress" SortExpression="EmailAddress">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EmailAddress") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblEmailAddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmailAddress") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtfooterEmailAddress" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEmailAddress" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtfooterEmailAddress" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revEmailAddress" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtfooterEmailAddress" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" 
                ErrorMessage="Please Enter Valid Email Address" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EditRecord">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update"
                            Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel"
                            Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit"
                            Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkInsert" runat="server" Text ="Insert" OnClick="lnkInsert_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="Silver" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        </asp:GridView>
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text ="Insert Record Successfully" Visible ="false" > </asp:Label>
```

Then on code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //check whether page is postback or not
    //if page is not postback at that time we bind the gridview
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
      //call the function BindGridView
        BindGridView();
    }
}

public void BindGridView()
{
    //here write connection string
    string strsql = DBConnection.sqlstr;

    //create object for sqlconnection
    SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(strsql);

    //here i use the query
    //create the object of sqlcommand
    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [User]", sqlcon);

    //create sqldataadapter object and give the sqlcommand as parameter
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
    //declare the dataset
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    //fill dataset using fill method of SqlDataAdapter
    adp.Fill(ds);

    //bind the GridView1
    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

On insert click

```
protected void lnkInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strsql = DBConnection.sqlstr;

    //create object for sqlconnection
    SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(strsql);

    //here i use the query
    string strQuery = "Insert into [User] (UserName,Address1,EmailAddress) values (@UserName,@Address1,@EmailAddress)";
    //create the object of sqlcommand
    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, sqlcon);
    //find the footer row for UserName And Assign the value
    sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtfooterUserName")).Text;
    sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@Address1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtfooterAddress1")).Text;
    sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@EmailAddress", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtfooterEmailAddress")).Text;
    //open the sql connection
    sqlcon.Open();
    // Execute the Insert Command In to Database
    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //close the sqlconnection
    sqlcon.Close();
    //if record successfully insert we display the message
    lblMessage.Visible = true;
    //bind grid view for latest record
    BindGridView();
}
```

Comment: Managed to edit it to my needs and actually works perfectly, thanks